# DoCmd.OpenForm WhereCondition: Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have two forms.
The first form is a continuous list of data containing basic customer information including a field called Customer_Name.
The second form is a detailed form which shows all the customer fields and includes a subform with the customers contacts listed from a C_Contacts table.

I have a button on the end of each record in Form 1 called Open_Details.

```vb
Private Sub Open_Details_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Customers", _
      WhereCondition:="Customer_Name=" & [Customer_Name]
End Sub
```

When I click the button on the Physical Sciences Inc. row I get a Syntax Error:

> Run-time error '3075':  Syntax error (missing operator) in query
> expression 'Customer_Name=Physical Sciences Inc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to get the quotes around that customer name - i.e.,

```
"Customer_Name=" & "'" & [Customer_Name] & "'"
```

Comment: Yes! That was it, exactly. Thanks so much!